# How to set a cooldown on tkinter keybind input

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In a basic graphical application I've been working on, there's a **problem where holding down a key sends keyboard input extremely quickly**, to the point where trying to slow it down with some kind of cooldown doesn't work.

It does work if the cooldown is substantial (>2 seconds cooldown), which is unacceptable for a lot of games.

For any program that automatically links a keypress to a `root.move` statement will allow extreme speeds across the screen.

Is there a way to limit keypress inputs? If not, is there a way to remove/cancel out the excessive inputs?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, please take some time to formulate the question short but sweet, and show us the code you have tried so far to solve this problem. When you have time, please read [ask]. Thanks a lot, and welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: @thenarfer
A little unclear on code formatting here, but essentially I set a global timer variable that is used to tell when a cooldown is over, i.e. if timer+1>time.time():
Also, timer will take the value of time.time() every time this if statement triggers. The problem is, this doesn't seem to work for extremely fast keyboard input, and won't even be noticable until the cooldown is 2+ seconds.

Comment: Maybe you could edit your question and make it easy to get a quick overview. That way it's easy to get the input of many people that stop by to check out the question :-)

Comment: @thenarfer is that better?

Comment: Actually I figured it out, just had to create a counter system instead of a timer system.

Comment: That's excellent! Please add your answer in a short and clear format with the code that solved your problem! It will help other people with similar issues in the future :-)

Answer (score 1):

This won't be consistent across platforms or other computers due to different input speeds, but using a simple counter to ensure it only fires once every 3 times is more than enough to slow it down to reasonable speeds.

```
lcounter=0
def left(event):
    global leftv,lcounter
    leftv=True
    if lcounter==2:
        playercoords[0]-=1
        render(playercoords[0],playercoords[1]+30)
        lcounter=0
    else:
        lcounter+=1
`
```